# How to Sum up all BigDecimal in list of Objects

Tags: java, spring-boot

was wondering if any of the lambda can achieve something like this
with the class provided here

```
public class DataDto {
    private BigDecimal baseAmt;
    private BigDecimal revenueAmt;
    private BigDecimal occupiedDays;
    private String timeUnit;
}

List<DataDto> data = {from db}

Map<String, BigDecimal> map = dataDtos().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DataDto ::getTimePoint,
                            Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, DataDto ::getBaseAmt)));
```

How to grouping by getTimePoint and add all the big decimal to particular fields and return to the list.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I can do it with a `for` loop. But I have not yet been able to do it with streams.

Let’s simplify your problem by defining a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) with only two member fields.

```
record Amount( LocalDate date , BigDecimal revenue ) { }
```

Make some example data. We have two `BigDecimal` values for each of two `LocalDate` keys. January 23rd has 7 and 42, while April 1 has 1.2 and 1.1.

```java
List < Amount > amounts =
        List.of(
                new Amount( LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) , new BigDecimal( "7" ) ) ,
                new Amount( LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.APRIL , 1 ) , new BigDecimal( "1.2" ) ) ,
                new Amount( LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.APRIL , 1 ) , new BigDecimal( "1.1" ) ) ,
                new Amount( LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) , new BigDecimal( "42" ) )
        );
```

Loop those.

```java
NavigableMap < LocalDate, BigDecimal > mapTotalByDate = new TreeMap <>();
for ( Amount amount : amounts )
{
    if ( mapTotalByDate.get( amount.date() ) == null )
    {
        mapTotalByDate.put( amount.date , amount.revenue );
    } else
    {
        mapTotalByDate.put( amount.date , mapTotalByDate.get( amount.date ).add( amount.revenue ) );
    }
}
```

> mapTotalByDate = {2022-01-23=49, 2022-04-01=2.3}

Or change that `for` loop to use `switch` rather than cascading `if`, as suggested by IntelliJ. I prefer this as it seems easier to read.

```java
for ( Amount amount : amounts )
{
    switch ( mapTotalByDate.get( amount.date() ) )
    {
        case null -> mapTotalByDate.put( amount.date , amount.revenue );
        default -> mapTotalByDate.put( amount.date , mapTotalByDate.get( amount.date ).add( amount.revenue ) );
    }
}
```

Eliminate one of lookup on the map.

```java
for ( Amount amount : amounts )
{
    BigDecimal subtotal = mapTotalByDate.get( amount.date() );
    switch ( subtotal )
    {
        case null -> mapTotalByDate.put( amount.date , amount.revenue );
        default -> mapTotalByDate.put( amount.date , subtotal.add( amount.revenue ) );
    }
}
```